# Why should you be careful when you use a Hall effect probe to measure magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, sensor

> **Question**: *Why* must you be careful with orientation when you use the hall effect probe to measure magnetic field?
>
> > **Background**: In a recent Physics 2 lab, we used a magnetic field sensor which I'm guessing is also a "Hall Effect Probe" because my professor said it was the same thing.

I know that the [Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) is where electrons moving through material are effected by a "Lorentz Force" that acts perpendicularly. I know that the electrons will essentially bend with more electrons to the right of the material then on the left

I also know that the *Size of the Voltage is directly proportial to the size of the electric current and the strength of the magnetic field*

Yet, I don't understand the question in regards to orientation?

I looked [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/hall.html) and wiki, and found nothing in regards specifically to orientation except that the '*hall probe is placed between magnetic pole pieces*'

Any help or advice would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hall effect is always at right angles to a current flow, and a Hall
sensor typically has two electrodes that sense the effect (the Hall voltage)
and which are located 'left' and 'right'.   But there's no effect for B field component parallel to the current flow, and the electrodes' position 'left'
and 'right' establish a second direction which is also a B field orientation that generates no effect (there's only Hall voltage perpendicular to the B direction).

So, a Hall sensor will only detect ONE COMPONENT, one directional part, of
the full three-dimensional vector B field.   A Hall sensor doesn't tell the magnitude of the B field vector.  It gives magnitude and direction (sign) of one of the three components of B.